# Session misunderstanding in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm working under rails and, as a beginner, I am trying to understand how the session feature works.
I put my sessions under active record, but when I do this:

```rb
    @request = Facebook::Request.parse_signed_request(params[:signed_request],
    Settings.facebook.app_secret) 
    puts session
    @admin = Admin.find_by_fb_userid(@request["user_id"])
    session[@request["user_id"]] = @admin ? @admin : nil
```

My session continue to display:

```
{}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the session value instead of whole session object:

```
puts session[@request['user_id']]
```

Do this before and after setting a session. And make sure you cleanup the session before testing this in browser (clear cookies or start incognito session).

And last but not least, it a bad idea to store whole objects in session. This way you are storing way more data in the session than needed. Try storing just the object id (in your case `@admin.id`) and then load it whenever needed.

Comment: What do you mean by printing the session value ?
Isn't that what I do by

    puts session

Comment: I mean to say use `puts session['something']` instead of just `puts session`.

Answer (score 2):

**How session works?**

HTTP is a stateless protocol.It means that it treats each request as an independent transaction
that is unrelated to any previous request so that the communication consists of *independent
pairs of requests and responses.*

A stateless protocol does not require the server **to retain session**
information or status about each communications partner for the duration of multiple requests.

The protocol provides no means of storing a user's data between requests.

Therefore, we use `Sessions`, which  allows us to **chain** multiple requests together into a conversation between client and server, so temporaly keep `data`.

`Session` is a `hash`, so you can add a data into session like to regular hash:

For example, to add a new order into the session can look like this:

*e.g. OrdersController*

```
def new
@order = current_user.orders.create   # creates a new order for current_user
session[:order] = @order.to_params    # adds order information to the session.
end
```

Sessions can store any kind of `string` data, but best served by keeping it as small as possible for both **speed** and **security**,as third party users can easily decode what information is stored in sessions.

**UPDATE**

by default `session data` are stored as `cookies` but `Rails`  allows to configure `session storage` in database using `ActiveRecordStore` or inmemory storage with `Redis` and `Redis store`. Each approach has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you very much.
So in this case, what is the purpose of the storage in cookie or database if it's not to keep it ?

I mean I worked recently in Node.js under Express and everytime a session is open, it's stored in database. So for a user, I always have his userID and I am able to retrieve his session easily.

Here I don't really know how to do that. Does it mean that in my parent controler I should have a method that recreate the session everytime as a before_action?

ps: Sorry for my english

Comment: See updated answer. Do create a new question,pls for this section as it is too broad topic to be covered here...

Answer (score 0):

Ok my fault was that I was working on a facebook app I guess and for every refresh, the session is reset by the peer.

But when I continued in my process, everything instantly worked.

And even if session is a stateless protocol, it is used, through the storage that is used to keep the session active all along the session.

Like in PHP or every single language